# It is possible I load images from JSON in Jssor Slider Gallery?

Tags: jquery, json, slider, gallery, jssor

I want to load images from Json in a Jssor Slider Gallery, anyone knows how I can do it?!
I did googled it but, i didnt see anyway to do it.
If it is not possible, would you guys, show me other free slider gallery that i could do it?!

Just for exemple. In owl-carousel gallery it's possible to do it:

```html
var owl = $("#owl-gallery");
   owl.owlCarousel({
        jsonPath : 'js/gallery.json',
  jsonSuccess : loadFotos,
        ...
        afterInit : function(elem){
          //my function loadFotos with json data
     }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can return the link of the images on json success and use that link as scr of the images.

Comment: Hi, i´m already doing this. But what i want to know is where i can put my funcion of loadFotos on jssor slider. I didnt see any callback for it.